# Why am I not getting a "some of your favorites have had new activity" notification?

Tags: bug, support, notifications, bookmarks

I know SO and other Stack Exchange sites give me a notification when there've been new answers/comments/edits on questions I've added to my favorites - I don't remember the exact wording, but it's one of those things that show up on top of the screen.

This site doesn't seem to be doing that, unless my memory is way off and all this content that looks new to me when I go back to my favorites has actually been there earlier.

Has anyone gotten this notification?  Does anyone know why it's not happening?  Is this just a feature that isn't on during private beta?

Comment: ....it does that? I've never gotten a notification of any sort for that.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think it is working on Sci-Fi either.

Comment: @Rarity - SO definitely does it, I got one just a couple of days ago - it's a bar across the top of the screen with just the notification and a link to favorites, similar to the notification when you get a new badge or privilege. Maybe there's some preference to turn it on somewhere, but if so, I can't find it...

Comment: @YannisRizos I haven't found it annoying so far, and I like getting it, but perhaps it's because it only happens intermittently, as Anna Lear said.  It's possible that it'd end up showing up too often if it really worked. Hard to tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no user preference for it, but in my experience the whole thing is ... intermittent at best.

As a workaround, you can check your profile page. The number of changes to your favourites will be shown as a number beside the "favorites" tab.

Comment: Good to know, thanks!  Any idea if there are plans to make it less intermittent in the future, or is that going to be the permanent state of the feature for a while?

Comment: @weronika I'll have to ask around and see what the intended state of it is.